# How to setup a rails 3 route for a nested resource and custom controller action

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a recommendation that is nested below Categories and Awards.

So Category/:id/awards/:id/recommendations/:id

I have an Assets model that handles paperclip attachments to the Recommendation.  A Recommendation has_many Assets, Assets belong_to :recommendation

In my Recommendation new/edit views I am rendering a form partial (as is normal) that gives the user the option to upload several assets.

If there are Assets already related, then it lists them. I am working on setting up a custom delete action on the recommendations controller.

My current link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Attachment", 
                {:controller => :recommendations, :action => :destroy_asset, :id => asset.id }, 
                {:remote => "true", :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this image?"} 
         %>
```

My Controller action:

```
def destroy_asset
    #@recommendation = Recommendation.find(params[:id])
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    @asset.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

routes: 
    resources :recommendations
    resources :categories do
        resources :awards do
            resources :recommendations 
        end
      end

I am still learning remote => true, and how to route this sucker.  Not sure if I need to have the route nested or not.  I tend to think not.  Since I have an Asset.id in my loop, I should just be able to execute the destroy without needing the Recommendation at all.

So the question/s: do I need a route to access a custom action in my recommendations_controller?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :categories do
    resources :awards do
        resources :recommendations 
           member do
              get :destroy_asset
           end
        end
    end 
end
```

Or If you only want only `destroy_asset` action under recommendation controller, do something like this :

```
resources :recommendations 
    member do
        get :destroy_asset
    end
end
```

Or If you want custom match, do something like this :

```
match "asset/:id/destroy_asset", :to => "recommendations#destroy_asset", 
:as=> "destroy_asset"
```

Comment: tried this and ran rake routes, which showed destroy_asset_category_award which then looks for the destroy_asset in the awards_controller.  Do I even need a route for this?  Am I able to just specify the action since I am already in the recommendation edit form view?

Comment: You can always write a custom route `match` that matches a specific controller action. See my Edit!!